# PHP: check for invalid characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, -, ., @)?

Tags: php, regex, validation

I would like to check if a string contains only these characters :

```
A-Z
a-z
0-9
-
@
_
.
```

The purpose is to check if a mail is valid in a form.

I am doing this :

```
if(preg_match('/[a-z0-9\._\-\@]/i', $email) === 0) {
        echo 'not valid';
    }

if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo 'not valid';
}
```

but is doesn’t return an error if there is a special character like

> test%@test.fr

Comment: Why use a regex *in addition to* `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`…? You're creating another [arbitrary subset of email addresses you're allowing people to use!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945002/476)

Comment: `/[a-z0-9\._\-\@]/i` succeeds if **one** character match.

Comment: There is `filter_var()` with an email flag, either sanitize or validation, which is the only thing you need

Comment: Note that Gmail users can use a `+` in their email to filter the incoming mail. Your regex doesn't take that into account.

Comment: your example of the email address is valid one, so the `filter_var` will not consider it as invalid. And for the `preg_match` check this out: https://eval.in/814651

Comment: Thank for these explanations. Usually, i only use `filter_var `It’s my client who is asking for these rules so i was trying to implement them. Bur your comments lead me to think i should dissuade him to apply these rules. And why the down vote ? The question is not correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> preg_match('/[a-z0-9._-\@]/i', $email)

This will return true if any valid characters are found but you want to match any *non-valid* characters - so invert the character class:

```
preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\._\-\@]/i', $email)
```

Alternatively you could require that it *only* contains the valid characters:

```
if (!(preg_match('/^([a-z0-9\._\-\@]+)$/', $email)) {
```

BTW as an email address (more specifically an ADDR_SPEC validator) this sucks big time - it will pass non-valid email addresses and fail valid ones.

Who told you that '%' is invalid in a mailbox name?

Currently I use this:

```
/^[a-z0-9\._%+!$&*=^|~#%'`?{}/\-]+@([a-z0-9\-]+\.){1,}([a-z]{2,20})$/gi
```

(which still excludes some valid ADDR_SPECs - but for specific reasons - and has some issues with idn)

...but would suggest you just use filter_var() and ditch the regex.

Comment: "invent" or "invert"?

Comment: It’s my client who is asking for these rules so i was trying to implement them. But thanks to your explanation, i realize it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `/[a-z0-9\._\-\@]/i` checks only of some of the listed characters are in the `$email`. It does not disallow any other characters in the `$email`.

In order to restrict the input to the listed characters only define a sequence of them (`[a-z0-9\._\-\@]+`, notice the `+` quantifier) and require it to be the only sequence in the input by surrounding with `^` and `$` (start of string and end of string anchors respectively):

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\._\-\@]+$/i', $email) === 0) {
    echo 'not valid';
}
```