# Regex for danish address

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to match danish addresses like:

- Ørestads Boulevard 2B
- Sankt Annæ Plads 32 5
- Syriensvej 24 6 st th

Requirements are:

- min 2 "words" (street and house number)

  - Samosvej 3
- Street can start/end with æøåÆØÅ

  - Ørestads Boulevard 33
  - Sankt Annæ Plads 33
- house number must start with number
- house number can contain numbers and capital letters (0-9A-ZÆØÅ)

  - Øresundsvej 2B
- house number max length is 5

  - Øresundsvej 2923B
- anything can come after house number

  - Øresundsvej 292 st th, Amager

So far I come up with this but I wonder if it could be optimized / "prettyfied"

```
/^([a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]{2,40}\.?\s{1}){1,}([0-9]){1,}.*$/
```

I can't use "Word Boundaries" (\w) because street can start/end with special chars like æøåÆØÅ. Is there any other way to do it other than \b?

Also my code doesn't check for house number length. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Adresses are a tough target for regex, since there's not a very strict pattern. What are you going to use this for? It says something about tolerances when creating a regex. Do you wish to validate a form, or are you searching text for adresses?

Comment: Im validating a "Address" form input field

Comment: There's no Danish address which will ever use a hyphen, or other "unusual" character? *"Something-van-something Plads"*? No? Sure?

Comment: Yes we use dashes in street names

Comment: Your current rule doesn’t allow for it. What else might you be missing?

Comment: @deceze not very helpful

Comment: I'm trying to point towards this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945002/476 At the very least you should obtain a database of all postal addresses in Denmark and test that your regex matches all of them, so as to avoid false negatives and user frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your regex seems to do the job you want. In javascript you are limited to one of the worst regex engines which are still in frequent use, so prettifying it is not all that simple.

```
/^
([a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]{2,40}\.?   # 1.
\s{1}){1,}                 # 2.
([0-9]){1,}                # 3.
.*$/
```

1. Are the adresses in Denmark limited to 40 character words? Can you be sure of that restriction?  You can match upper+lower case with a single group: `A-z`
   If you were using another flavour of regex, I would recommend using the unicode language grouping (`\p{L}`) instead of that character group. See an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/Okbsrz/1)
2. `\s{1}` is redundant, you can safely remove `{1}`.
   As for the `{1,}` following the group there, it can be written in short form as `+`
3. As for the length of street number, you are accepting anything after the house number in any case, so you need some additional match criteria at the end.
   Changing the end to this does the limit thing: `([0-9]){1,5}\w?(\s.*)?$`

All in all, the regex could look like this:

```
^([A-zæøåÆØÅ]{2,40}\.?\s)+([0-9]){1,5}\w?(\s.*)?$
```

See it work: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Okbsrz/6)

Short disclaimer: In the examples on regex101, you see some matches spanning 2 lines. This is because the last `\s` matches the newline character and `.*` matches the rest of that line. If you validate fields in a form that is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: The house number limit only works if the string ends with whitespace or line break. I guess that's what you mean with the disclaimer??

Comment: That was not my intention with it, I'm sorry. I changed it a little bit to only require the space if it wanted to match anything beyond. I've also found a few other things.

Comment: What's this: A-z ? Could i just use \w ?

Comment: `\w` also matches numerals, as well as underscore. `A-z` means it matches from a-z in both upper and lower case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I accepted your answer!

Comment: I needed to add \- to the rexex as there can be dash in addresses.